# Autocomplete issue into bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-autocomplete, bootstrap-modal

I have a display problem in the jQuery autocomplete inside a modal dialog bootstrap.

When I mouse scroll, the results do not remain attached to the input.

Is there a way to solve this?

Here [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/TtxqG/):

```
.ui-autocomplete-input {
  border: none; 
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #DDD !important;
  padding-top: 0px !important;
  z-index: 1511;
  position: relative;
}
```

**EDIT**
I found the problem:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  position: fixed;
  .....
}
```

If the modal has scroll the issue remains!

Here [JsFiddle/1](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/TtxqG/1/).

Answer (score 122, accepted):

The position is right that it is "absolute", while you need to specify this as an option to [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo):

```
$( ".addresspicker" ).autocomplete( "option", "appendTo", ".eventInsForm" );
```

Where it can anchor the box with the results in any element, I have to stop it from being anchored to the form's class!

Here [is a working JsFiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/lughino/TtxqG/4/).

Comment: Thank you. If anyone had my same issue, it applies also to jquery [autocomplete combobox](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox). Just add `appendTo: ".your-form-in-modal"` to `.autocomplete({` in the `_createAutocomplete` function.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However if you remove the textarea, We do see a scrollbar inside modal-body. Any idea how to fix this? Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TtxqG/410/

Comment: or simply add `.ui-front` to modal window

Comment: teran : This is the quickest answer, thanks ! More accurate, add `.ui-front` to your `.modal-body` div.

Comment: If indicating appendTo option does not resolve your issue, you can do `appendTo: $(id or class).parent()`

Comment: Nice.
if you're using the same function for different cases this could be a general solution: `appendTo: $(selector).closest('form')`

Comment: @teran: "simply add .ui-front to modal window" this is amazing ! thank you

Answer (score 57):

The above solution talking about the `z-index` issue worked:

```
.ui-autocomplete { z-index:2147483647; }
```

Make sure you put it before your `.js` script responsible for handling the modal AND autocomplete logic.

Comment: If you read the comments of the other answer, which is exactly the same as yours, the problem is not solved in this way!

Comment: Worked for me. Regardless of the nay-sayer.

Comment: Perfect. No JS. With CSS, this is the best solution.

Comment: Your solutions worded for me too. Thank you

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Comment: 2147483647 is a bit overkill. Bootstrap modal nowadays is `z-index: 1055;` thus setting z-index to 2000 would be more than enough.

Answer (score 32):

[Check out the appendTo documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-appendTo):

> When the value is null, the parents of the input field will be
>   checked for a class of ui-front. If an element with the ui-front class
>   is found, the menu will be appended to that element.

So **just add the class "ui-front" to the parent element** and the autocomplete will be correctly displayed inside the modal.

Comment: Works great with Foundation 5 reveal-modal.

Comment: Does not work for me.  So far, the only thing which does work is hacking the `z-index` which feels wrong.

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 26):

With add the class **"ui-front"** to the div parent element and the autocomplete will be correctly displayed inside the PopUp For Me.

Comment: While the accepted answer will work, I feel like this should be the correct answer, as the docs indicate this as the default behavior: `If an element with the ui-front class is found, the menu will be appended to that element`

Comment: you repeat an already answer 2 years later. See original answer from @Fernando Pinheiro

Answer (score 15):

The actual issue is that the Bootstrap Modal has a higher Z-index than any other element in the page. Thus, auto complete actually works - but it gets hidden behind the dialog.

You just need to add this in any of your added `css` files:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index:2147483647;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not just that and not solve anything by putting a parameter z-index so high!
The problem is not only the fact that it remains below the modal, but if you make it scroll the page the results do not remain attached to the input, and if you re-read the question well will be explained.
However, the problem is resolved, see answer above!

Answer (score 6):

To fix this I just needed to alter in the `css` file by jQuery:

```
.ui-front {
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Note: Add this css after jquery-ui.css & jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 4):

just try adding this:

```css
.ui-autocomplete {
  z-index: 215000000 !important;
}
```

Just make sure you give a high value to the property and **DO ADD**

> !important

It really matters. The latter will tell your browser to execute this rule first, before any other of the same class.
Hope it will help

Comment: This is not responsive design

Comment: I don't get you @gtzinos

Answer (score 1):

## In file: styles.css

```
.cdk-overlay-container
{
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

I tried all solutions in my internal css file of the component, and nothing works, only when moved it to styles.css.

good luck

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
.ui-front {
    z-index: 5000;
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `appendTo` option resolved this issue. It appended the menu to one of the objects in the bootstrap model.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by this....

```
/********************************************************************
*           CORREZIONE PER L'AUTOCOMPLETE EXTENDER di AJAX TOOLKIt  *
********************************************************************/
ul[id*='_completionListElem'] {
    z-index: 215000000 !important;
}
```

Autocomplete extender completion list has an utomated ID like this
id='*_completionListElem*'

so you must push up the z-index .. upper then the bootstrap modal panel ;)

Hope it helps

Answer (score -1):

```
.ui-front {
    z-index: 9999;
}

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog ui-front">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```