# Display searched results in modal box search

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

i had one search box in inside modal body . i created one search option for modal i had the result also but outside of modal search working fine but inside modal search results couldn't display any ideas?

My Modal Code :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" >
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="job-title-select2" style="display:none;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" id="jobsearch" name="jobsearch" class="form-control" value="" placeholder="Enter Job Title....">
                        <input type="submit" id="title-button" class="btn btn-info btn" value="Confirm">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code :

```
$("#jobsearch").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{route('searchexistingjob')}}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {term : request.term},
                    success: function(data) {
                         /////
                    }
                });
            },
        minLength: 3,
});
```

output result in console :

```
[{id: 6, value: "Analytical thinker"}]
```

controller return value :

```
array (
```

0 => 
  array (
    'id' => 6,
    'value' => 'Analytical thinker',
  ),
)

so i need to display the value.

Comment: I have posted the answer let me know if there is any confusion.

Comment: The first question is where do you want the results to be displayed?

Comment: Create an empty DIV in your modal to hold the result of the search and then place `date.id` and `data.value` into this blank DIV

Comment: but how to select that value again and process ex:  if the value was john means again i can process that form how this display workes like selection option?

Comment: please provide snippet if possible so we can check what is the exact problem

Comment: snippet was not possible because data problem - see am searching some data using autocomplete search - am typing some words means it will display matched value from database but this this works only in outside of modal but  am doing inside modal means it will not display

Comment: are you able to view the text box in modal?

Comment: yes - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133654/autocomplete-issue-into-bootstrap-modal     i need result like this  - i tried but  not displaying u have any idea means tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your server side data will be like

```
$data = array (array ( 'id' => 6, 'value' => 'Analytical thinker'));
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in your ajax success pass your data back to ajax `source` response like below.

```
response(data);
```

So your ajax code will be,

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{route('searchexistingjob')}}",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {term : request.term},
    success: function(data) {
        response(data);
    }
});
```

**Note:** If all works fine but still not displaying surely `z-index` causing the problem. So add below style and try,

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    position:absolute;
    cursor:default;
    z-index:4000 !important
}
```

Comment: but OP is using dataType: "json" and getting JSON back from the server so doing a JSON.parse(data) will be wrong  - this error coming while parsing data

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have edited the answer and problem is in setting `z-index`.

Answer (score -1):

use the below code in your success function

```
    obj = JSON.parse(data);

    $("#jobsearch").val(obj.value);
    $("#job-title-select2").show();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
```

Comment: OP is using `dataType: "json"` and getting JSON back from the server so doing a `JSON.parse(data)` will be wrong

Comment: You are also putting the result of the search into a button?

Comment: i have changed the button id to job search
please try again you code was edited after my answer

Comment: so you are not able to see the dropdown values while searching right?

Comment: @Prateik Darji  yea, outside of modal it working fine but inside modal only problem

Comment: you need to set z-index